# How to add cell to all rows of a table with vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I desire to add a table cell from the right of any last cell, of my table's rows:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("td").forEach((element) => {
    element.insertRow(-1);
});
```

```html
<section class="allEnglishSections">
    <h2>Conditioning</h2>
    <table>
        <tr><th>English</tr></th>
        <tr><td>if</td></tr>
        <tr><td>else</td></tr>
    </table>
</section>
```

I get this error:

> Error {
>   "message": "Script error.",
>   "filename": "",
>   "lineno": 0,
>   "colno": 0
>   }

but I don't understand the problem from it; what is wrong?

Comment: Press "Run code snippet". `Uncaught TypeError: element.insertRow is not a function @ JS line 2` - seems pretty self-explanatory to me, a `<td>` does not have an `insertRow` method

Comment: @CertainPerformance funny, when I clicked the button I didn't see that error...

Comment: The only thing I saw is what I copied...

Comment: What browser are you using? `Script error` is usually the error message given when the error is opaque or `JSON.parse`, but here, the error should not be opaque, and displays as expected on FF 56 and Chrome newest

Comment: I used Edge when watching this...

Comment: Ah, thanks, that's good to know. Looks like Edge has some problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through all the *tr* and insert the td with [**`insertAdjacentHTML()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) if any *td* exists in the row:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tr")).forEach((tr) => {
  if(tr.querySelector('td'))
    tr.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<td>last</td>');
});
```

```html
<section class="allEnglishSections">
    <h2>Conditioning</h2>
    <table>
        <tr><th>English<th></tr>
        <tr><td>if</td></tr>
        <tr><td>else</td></tr>
    </table>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `insertRow` method on tables in JavaScript. It's not like a spreadsheet or database. You need to create a new element and append it to each row.

```
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr')
const cell = document.createElement('td')

rows.forEach(row => {
  const cells = row.querySelectorAll('td')
  if (cells.length) row.appendChild(cell)
})
```